# Colouring one side of a rectangle defined by \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

I create a rectangle like this:

`\draw (2,2) -- (2,4) -- (6,4) -- (6,2) -- (2,2);`

I would like to give the red colour to the side defined by points (2,2) and (2,4).

I tried doing

`\draw [red] (2,2) -- (2,4) -- (6,4) -- (6,2) -- (2,2);`

but this colours the entire rectangle.

Comment: Better end cycles with `-- cycle` rather than `-- (a,b)` where `(a,b)` are the coordinates of the first point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there may be other ways but just splitting in to two is a simple possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red] (2,2) -- (2,4);
\draw (2,4) -- (6,4) -- (6,2) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry sir we don't serve experts in TikZ questions. I'm gonna have to ask you to leave. Hmm, I think you have been called by the L3 team to meet at the reception...

Comment: @percusse seriously if there is a way to have it as a continuous cycle and change colour you should post, of course it's not so obvious with a rectangle but a smooth curve would be hard to keep smooth if done as two paths I'd guess

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change the pen properties on a single path.

Comment: @percusse I knew I should stick to picture mode

Answer (score 2):

Another option: draw the rectangle and overwrite in red the side you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) rectangle (6,4);
\draw [red] (2,2) -- (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]